# Batch script to move files by filename initials to new created folders

Tags: batch-file

I've created this batch script and when running, it creates folders same with the filenames and moves these files in the newly created folders.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

I'm looking to modify this and do the following:
For filenames (.htm) starting with "22.*" create a folder named "22" and move them inside.
For filenames starting with "40.*" create a folder named "40" and move them inside etc.

Anyone knows how?

Comment: could you please share an example of a complete filename (and confirm they all follow the same format)?

Comment: of course! Here is an example list of files starting with "20.*" and "40.*"
`20.003.11.2982 
20.003.19.2960 
20.003.32.5020 
20.003.39.5984 
20.003.51.2496 
40.003.32.5191 
40.003.72.3514 
40.003.72.7208 
40.003.81.5975`

Comment: Are the files all consistantly named, meaning does it have the same standard all the time?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes Gerhard correct! First two numbers are always the same.

Comment: and according to your code, there are only such files-to-be-copied and files named `organize.*` in the folder?

Comment: @Compo And how Robocopy will create folders with filename initials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=." %%i in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
if /i not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
    mkdir %%i >nul 2>&1
    move %%i.* %%i
  )
 )
```

Keep in mind, this does not cater for duplicate files that might exist in the destination folder, for that you need to decide if you want to overwrite or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it. It creates the folders correctly but it doesn't move the files inside. Any idea why? If it helps, all the files are .htm files.

Comment: Sorry man, I used `mv` which is a linux command I have on my device, forgot it should be `move`

Comment: You're absolutely right, i missed this too. It works perfectly! Thank you so much Gerhard, i really appreciate your help!